# How can I get keyboard input in (BareBones) C?

Tags: c, osdev, bare-metal

I'm in 32bit protected mode (BAREBONES) C I'm making 32bit DOS called YourDOS, but I can't get input.

here is the code for the kernel That I got from a template on repl.it:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
 
/* Check if the compiler thinks you are targeting the wrong operating system. */
#if defined(__linux__)
#error "You are not using a cross-compiler, you will most certainly run into trouble"
#endif
 
/* This tutorial will only work for the 32-bit ix86 targets. */
#if !defined(__i386__)
#error "This tutorial needs to be compiled with a ix86-elf compiler"
#endif
 
/* Hardware text mode color constants. */
enum vga_color {
    VGA_COLOR_BLACK = 0,
    VGA_COLOR_BLUE = 1,
    VGA_COLOR_GREEN = 2,
    VGA_COLOR_CYAN = 3,
    VGA_COLOR_RED = 4,
    VGA_COLOR_MAGENTA = 5,
    VGA_COLOR_BROWN = 6,
    VGA_COLOR_LIGHT_GREY = 7,
    VGA_COLOR_DARK_GREY = 8,
    VGA_COLOR_LIGHT_BLUE = 9,
    VGA_COLOR_LIGHT_GREEN = 10,
    VGA_COLOR_LIGHT_CYAN = 11,
    VGA_COLOR_LIGHT_RED = 12,
    VGA_COLOR_LIGHT_MAGENTA = 13,
    VGA_COLOR_LIGHT_BROWN = 14,
    VGA_COLOR_WHITE = 15,
};
 
static inline uint8_t vga_entry_color(enum vga_color fg, enum vga_color bg) 
{
    return fg | bg << 4;
}
 
static inline uint16_t vga_entry(unsigned char uc, uint8_t color) 
{
    return (uint16_t) uc | (uint16_t) color << 8;
}
 
size_t strlen(const char* str) 
{
    size_t len = 0;
    while (str[len])
        len++;
    return len;
}
 
static const size_t VGA_WIDTH = 80;
static const size_t VGA_HEIGHT = 25;
 
size_t terminal_row;
size_t terminal_column;
uint8_t terminal_color;
uint16_t* terminal_buffer;
 
void terminal_initialize(void) 
{
    terminal_row = 0;
    terminal_column = 0;
    terminal_color = vga_entry_color(VGA_COLOR_LIGHT_GREY, VGA_COLOR_BLACK);
    terminal_buffer = (uint16_t*) 0xB8000;
    for (size_t y = 0; y < VGA_HEIGHT; y++) {
        for (size_t x = 0; x < VGA_WIDTH; x++) {
            const size_t index = y * VGA_WIDTH + x;
            terminal_buffer[index] = vga_entry(' ', terminal_color);
        }
    }
}
 
void terminal_setcolor(uint8_t color) 
{
    terminal_color = color;
}
 
void terminal_putentryat(char c, uint8_t color, size_t x, size_t y) 
{
    const size_t index = y * VGA_WIDTH + x;
    terminal_buffer[index] = vga_entry(c, color);
}
 
void terminal_putchar(char c) 
{
    terminal_putentryat(c, terminal_color, terminal_column, terminal_row);
    if (++terminal_column == VGA_WIDTH) {
        terminal_column = 0;
        if (++terminal_row == VGA_HEIGHT)
            terminal_row = 0;
    }
}
 
void terminal_write(const char* data, size_t size) 
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        terminal_putchar(data[i]);
}
 
void terminal_writestring(const char* data) 
{
    terminal_write(data, strlen(data));
}
 void terminal_newline()
{
  terminal_row++;
  terminal_column = 0;
}
void terminal_setcolumn(VAL) 
{
  terminal_column = VAL;
}
void kernel_main(void) 
{
    /* Initialize terminal interface */
    terminal_initialize();
 
    /* Newline support is left as an exercise. I DID IT! */
  terminal_setcolumn(17);
  terminal_setcolor(VGA_COLOR_GREEN);
    terminal_writestring("YourDOS! 2023 StudentDEV...");
  terminal_newline();
  terminal_setcolumn(15);
  terminal_setcolor(VGA_COLOR_CYAN);
  terminal_writestring("'List' for a List of command's.");
  terminal_newline();
  terminal_setcolor(VGA_COLOR_WHITE);
  terminal_writestring("YourDOS$");
}
```

I've THOUGHT about trying to use mov ah, 0 and [ insert code for an int 16 like thing] but I don't know how exactly to do it, and I've got a Garbeled input system from I tried fixing that, but it didn't work.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] your question to clarify. -- The source you show has nothing to do with the issue, it targets the other direction: visible output to a user at the screen. You might need to read your lesson's material to find out how to access the hardware that provides keyboard input. Please show us what you learned about that so far, and where exactly you stumble.

Comment: In addition to what was already mentioned, this function `void terminal_setcolumn(VAL) ` should provide a type for the parameter. Implicit int type is an artefact from previous centuries.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at this website.
https://wiki.osdev.org/Keyboard

It describes how to get input from PS/2 keyboard.
I suppose you are using an emulator like qemu?
qemu simulates your keyboard as PS/2 to the kernel, so you don't have to worry about writing an USB stack.

Maybe instead of staying in 32-bit, it would be easier to change mode to long mode.

For PS/2 you do not even need interrupts, since you are just reading and writing to a serial port.